# Markdown help doesn't explain [tag:]

Tags: bug, markdown

You can mark StackExchange tags like so [example](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/example), using [tag:].

This is not explained anywhere I can find in the Markdown help.

This probably applies across StackExchange sites.

Edited to add: Now fixed: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be moved to http://meta.stackoverflow.com since it is relevant for the entire SE network. However, since there is no migration path to there yet, I suggest we close this Skeptics Meta question and ask the OP to repost it on Stackoverflow Meta.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but I thought the same StackExchange team monitor all the meta sites for bug-tagged items.

Comment: @Oddthinking They might, but it's not a Skeptics related bug and therefore should be posted on the general meta.

Comment: We do keep an eye on all the child metas.